# como puedo hacer para que no me coja numeros negativos en java

Tags: java, poo

Buen dia

me pueden ayudar con una mi cadigo ya que me piden que no valide numeros negativos e intentado varias veces pero no me da el ejercicio tiene el siguiente enunciado
Cree una clase llamada Carro en el que contenga las siguientes características:
a. Sus atributos son :
i. Marca.
ii.Modelo.
iii capacidad
iv matricula
v precio
c. Cree el objeto.
d. Imprima la información por consola.
e que no valide numeros negativos
solo me falta el ultimo  e intentado varias veces pero no me bota un error

adjunto mi codigo con el que intente hacer la validacion pero no me aparece en pantalla y al momento de intentar inicializar la variabale no preico_carro me lo confunde con el de precio entonces no se que hacer  si deba mover la llave del while hasta el final o dejarla en la posicion donde esta si me pueden orientar se los agradeceria  :

package ejercico1_clases_y_objetos;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class carro
{
//atributos del objeto carro

```
     String marca;
     String modelo;
     String color;
     String capacidad;
     String matricula;
     float precio;
     String precio1;
    
     static Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
//nombre del objeto 
        
carro car=new carro(); // Se_crea_el_objeto 
car.precio=200000;

while(car.precio<0) {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\n error:digite un valor mayor a cero");
     car.precio1 = teclado.nextLine();
     if(car.precio>0) {
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n digite el valor del carro ");
         
     }else{
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n numero no valido ingrese un numero valido ");
         
     }
}
car.marca=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n   Por favor digita la marca del carro a comprar: ");
car.modelo=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n  ¿Cual es el modelo de carro que desea comprar ?: ");
car.color=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n   Por favor diga el color que desea  su carro: ");
car.capacidad=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Por favor indique de cuanta capacidad desea el carro: ");
car.matricula=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Por favor diga la matricula para su vehiculo: ");
     
    
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El carro que decide comprar es:"+car.marca+ "\n El modelo es:"+car.modelo+"\n El color es:"+car.color+"\n la capacidad es:"
+car.capacidad+"\n La matricula es:"+car.matricula +"\n la cantidad a pagar del carro es: $"+car.precio+" COP "); 
       
   
    }
  }
```

Comment: en donde se podrían ingresar esos números negativos?? todos tus atributos excepto el precio son de tipo cadena ...

Answer (score -1):

Hubiera sido bueno que incluyeras el código donde haces el intento de validación porque ese código que pusiste no sirve de nada, pero bueno, imagino que la validación debe ser cuando intentes ingresar los datos. En ese caso deberías preguntar si lo que ingresa el usuario comienza con un signo negativo con startsWith()

Comment: ya subi el codigo con el cual realice el intento que no me  vota lo que nesesito de que me deje ingresar los datos por pantalla